# Android check WIFI status (disconnected or user changed WIFI) How to FLAG it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, wifi

I is there a way to Flag if a WIFI connection got disconnected/ dropped off OR if the user actually changed the WIFI network ?

I need my app to do :
Connect to a WIFI XYZ, if XYZ get disconnect (FLAG 1) or dropped off Then reconnect to XYZ.
But is the user change to another wifi BTOpen (FLAG 2) then allow the connect and Stop my service.
If user connect to XYZ again then start the loop again.

What I got so far is :

```
    <!-- WIFI Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverWifi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".ServiceWifiMonitor" />
    <receiver android:name=".ServiceController" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action   android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
    myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    conManager  = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    networkInfo = conManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);


    boolean isConnected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    int reconnectedCount = myApplication.getReconnectedCount();


    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {


        if("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction())) {


            //Start and Stop Service
            if(myApplication.isReconnect()) startServiceWifiMonitor(); else stopServiceWifiMonitor();



            if (isConnected) {
                //There is a WIFI Connection
                myApplication.setConnectedWifi(NetworkUtil.getCurrentSSID(context));
                myApplication.setWifiStatus("connected");




                if (NetworkUtil.isConnectedToXYZ(context)) {
                    startServiceWifiMonitor();

                    if(pref.getisFirstTime()) 
                    {
                        myApplication.setWifiByChoise("XYZ");
                        pref.setisFirstTime(false);
                    }
                    else { myApplication.setisReconnect(true); }
                }
                else {
                    //Connected to different NetWork
                    if(myApplication.isReconnect() && NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context)) 
                    {
                        //ReConnect to XYZ
                        NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                        myApplication.setReconnectedCount(reconnectedCount++);
                    }
                    else { resetValues("AAAA"); }
                }


            }//end if
            else 
             {
                if(NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context) && myApplication.getWifiByChoise().equals("XYZ")) 
                {
                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(reconnectedCount++);
                }
                else { resetValues(""); }
            }
        }//end CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

Service Monitor:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand > Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        objHandler.postDelayed(mTasks, 1000);

    return START_STICKY;
}//end onStartCommand



private Runnable mTasks = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if(myApplication.getWifiByChoise().equals("XYZ") && NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context)) {              
            try
             {
                //Get the numbers of Reconnection
                int count = myApplication.getReconnectedCount();

                if(!NetworkUtil.isWifiConnected(context)) 
                {   

                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setisReconnect(true);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(count++); 
                }

                if(!NetworkUtil.isConnectedToXYZ(context)) 
                {   

                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setisReconnect(true);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(count++);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        else { stopSelf(); }
        int ms_interval = 3000;
        objHandler.postDelayed(mTasks, ms_interval);
    }
};//end Runnable mTasks
```

The problem with my app is that :
It crashed the device, Seems like its eating up all the memory ram.
sometimes with the wifi XYZ get disconnect  it wont connect again and if user change to another wifi, it won't allow the connection.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Check the network connected Name by using:

```
public String getWifiName(Context context) {
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
         WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
         if (wifiInfo != null) {
            DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
            if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
                return wifiInfo.getSSID();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

if this name matches your networkSSID, i.e. XYZ, then resume the service, else if it doesn't match, then stop the service:

```
if getWifiName(this).compareTo("XYZ") == 0 {  //XYZ is your network name on which you want to resume the service
    //code to resume
} else {
    //code to stop the service
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I handle it in my app:

```
public class WifiStateWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MainActivity activity;

    public WifiStateWatcher(MainActivity activity) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SupplicantState supState;
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();

        if (supState.equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED)) {
            //we are connected to Wi-Fi network
        } else {
            //we lost Wi-Fi connectivity
        }
    }
}
```

You will need `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is almost correct. you need to check the network ssd name with the user connected wifi name.If it matched then do your part.

```
WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    WifiInfo networkInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null) {
        DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(networkInfo .getSupplicantState());
        if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED ) {
            return networkInfo.getSSID();
        } 
    } 
} 
return null;
```

Now you have the network SSID so try to check with the your wifi name and SSID then you will get  to know the connection status.....
Happy Programming

Answer (score 0):

Also just checked this and found out that the main difference is:

```
/** IP traffic should be available. */
DetailedState.CONNECTED
```

and:

```
/**
 * …
 * This state indicates that the supplicant has completed its
 * processing for the association phase and that data connection is
 * fully configured. Note, however, that there may not be any IP
 * address associated with the connection yet. Typically, a DHCP
 * request needs to be sent at this point to obtain an address.
 */
SupplicantState.COMPLETED
```

So to trust that wifi is completely up, i now added the checks that:

```
boolean isConnected = activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

and **DetailedState.CONNECTED** :)

happy coding